# Bind TextBox fields to Object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hey if you have a object for example `Person` with properties `FirstName`, `LastName`, `BirthDate`. Do you need to get every property separately?

Like this in the ViewModel.cs:

```
private string _FirstName;
public string FirstName
{
     get { return _FirstName; }
     set 
     {
         _FirstName = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName"); 
     }
}
```

And this in the View.xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I tried this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

So that I don't need to type every single property. Is this possible? And how exactly?

Comment: What is you question exactly?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad if it is possible to just bind to Person and then the properties of it.

Comment: You will need to bind every property. XAML can't do magic (unless you're looking for a property-grid like control that "Dumps" every public property on your object

Comment: You can set the DataContext of the View to Person and then there is no need to say `Person.FirstName` just say `FirstName`. Are you looking for this?

Comment: Its also possible to inject the INotifyPropertyChanged during compilation: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: However it is perfectly possible to chain property access. So if `Person` itself is a property inside the `DataContext` and `FirstName` is a property of `Person`, then your second example would be working - your problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @grek40 maybe in the RaisePropertyChanged? Do I still need to do this for every property? I mean in "private Person Person get and set"

Comment: You need to raise property changed events for any property that might change after XAML bindings are established. First please edit your question with a complete example, then it's worth talking about necessary changes. This discussion is completely hypothetical as is.

Comment: However, in case you are mainly worried about the efford of writing observable properties with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then I strongly suggest you just use a custom visual studio snippet - then observable properties will come as easy as their primitive counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern to follow:

**Model**

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Person : Notifier 
{
    private string _firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(); //No need to pass "FirstName".
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class PersonViewModel : Notifier
{
    private Person _person;

    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set
        {
            _person= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(); //No need to pass "Person".
        }
    }
}
```

**View** (this View's `DataContext` is assumed to be an instance of `PersonViewModel` class)

```
<!-- other codes -->
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Person}">
    <!-- other codes -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <!-- other codes -->
</Grid>
<!-- other codes -->
```